# how to specify the phone number?

Tags: mysql

while creating the table in mysql 5.1  im getting an error while i specify the phone number as integer.

error is 'out of range value'.

i know i can specify the number as varchar.
i just want to know is their any other method ?

```
create table emp(
    ename varchar(20), 
    ecity varchar(10),
    salary double,
    enumber integer,
    eaddress varchar(40),
    depttname varchar(25)
);
```

Insert:

```
insert into emp 
values('priya','delhi',40000,9958465876,'b-64 janak puri new delhi','manager');
```

> ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'enum' at row 1

Comment: Since it is not going to be used for mathmatical purposes it should be a string

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you prefer storing it as an integer?

Answer (score 2):

Just change the datatype for enumber to BigInt might do the trick

Comment: Although `bigint` has enough space to hold this values, phone numbers are not meant to be used for mathematical purposes. I would store them as strings (`char` or `varchar`)

Comment: @Barranka:- I fully agree with you that if there is not any specific requirement to use int or BIGINT for storing phone numbers. Otherwise varchar should be prefered

Comment: @RahulTripathi The only possible consideration I can think of is the space required (`BIGINT` requires 8 bytes, and `VARCHAR` requires as much bytes as the lenght of the string stored, plus one). If the table is small, this consideration is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

An Integer in mysql has a max value of 2147483647, or 4294967295 if you use an unsigned integer.  This means that most values will be out of range by default.  You could use a BIGINT, with a signed range of 9223372036854775807 and an unsigned range of 18446744073709551615.  That would be enough, even with international dialing taken into account, I think.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use `varchar` to store phone numbers. But if there is any specific reason to take it then you can use `BIGINT` as currently you are facing the problem of range of int which is ,maximum at `4294967295`.

Answer (score 2):

Phone numbers are one of the few exceptions to the rule of not storing numbers as strings. This is because:

- Oftentimes the numeric representation is larger than what can be stored in the field.
- Some phone numbers have leading zeroes that should not be stripped off, eg: `0014255550177`
- You may want/need to store non-numeric characters with the phone number like `+`

Just make sure that you go the extra mile with your input validation on the field so that the phone numbers are stored in a consistent format if you want to do something like search for records matching a particular phone number.

ie: `780-555-1234`, `780 555-1234`, `780.555.1234` should all have their superfluous characters removed and be stored as `7805551234`.